Kotlin Coding capabilities with the new WFF
We developed Watchfaces for a health app that show several information (graphical curves, different values like Insulin BG value, Insulin on Board, Carb on Board, ...)
One watchface can be tuned without any coding from final user (all the information, images, font are included into a zip file to be shown within a "customized Watchface" (convertion between zip file content and watchface layout is done by code to tune the layout, visibility, text color, positionning, size, font according to bitmaps, font and a structured json file included)...
I just discovered the new WFF format, but I understood reading quickly the documentation that it's completly "locked"...
So my question is: is it possible, with Kotlin code (included into the associated App installed within the Watch) to update the elements included into a WFF watchface (replace an image by another, tune the color of text according to a value received by the phone, update text according to received values change position x, y, or width, heigh of a text, of an image, change a font, include a custom graph to show colored curves...
Currently I didn't try anything, I just received a warning about scared users who lost their favorite watchfaces after buying their latest Watch (Wear OS 5)
Just as an example, within watch, one watchface is installed (named "Custom WF") and user can send all these watchfaces (and much more) from the main app, they can tune their own WF...


In above screenshots imagine the face of the unicorn (AIMICO) is happy within range or sad when Blood glucose value is too high or too low, same for the drop of blood,.. All these watchfaces can be tuned only with a zip file sent to the watch and used by kotlin code to update the background, ImageViews or TextViews of the layout...
I would like to be able to do the same with latest watches with Wear OS 5...

As far as I am aware it is not possible to add code to the WFF as it's just xml... If there is a way to do so google hasn't released any info about it once big companies (Facer, for example), has already declared that their app won't be available on new watches with wear os 5

actually i'm a bit "scared" too because our app depends on a few functions like a big click-listener on the watch face, a non-clickable step-counter and so on which have some logic behind it. getting a gw7 tomorrow ....

It seems that source data to show within a watchface cannot be customized... (just a list of Hardcoded kays if I undestand correctly https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/wff/common/attributes/source-type
On our side 80% of information we show within our watchface will NEVER be within an hardcoded closed list of source-type... We absolutly need custom values.

I already warned the 12000 users of our app (facebook and discord groups) to NOT buy wear OS 5 watches if they want to still use our watchfaces... (they only works with Wear OS 4 and older versions)
It's just not possible to have nice Watchfaces like we currently have, especially for children with diabet with complications...
I'm not againt ne new WFF format if it can reduce consumption for most of existing simple WF, but according to me it's a shame to have locked all previous watchfaces compatibility and kotlin features required for advanced usage and custom data management...

Agree, they should let users decide whether they want to use an "optimized" watchface or not...I'm honestly just tired of Google, they reject updates for ridiculous ui guidelines (sometimes there isn't even nothing wrong) , they don't give us clear information, don't provide a good channel of communication, and they keep changing things all the time, I'm not a company, I can't keep up with their pace... Just to clarify Philoul, the current watchfaces will work on wear os 5 as long as the watch didn't come with wear os 5 by default, in other words the users can update just not buy a new watch

Thanks for your answer @dect
So does it mean that the capability within Wear OS 5 is existing but only locked by Google ?
Do you know if there is a way to unlock it (with dev mode or with adb ?)

I believe so, if you read answer for the question "What does this mean for you today?" from Facer (here https://community.facer.io/t/important-samsung-galaxy-watch7-ultra-compatibility-update/93887) you will see the info about the update. Also, Google is announcing the incompatibility for watches with Wear os 5 "pre-installed" instead of just wear os 5... About unlocking I have no idea on how to do it, or even if there is a way, but as a seller it doesn't do much, we cannot publish watchfaces that are in a different format than the WFF (this info is also somewhere in a doc)

so we just received a bunch of galaxy watch 7 and i can confirm: i can install my app, but the watchface is missing. even if installed via debugger. since our app is for old people we have some special behaviour in our watchface connected to our app.
this is really annoying because google said that apps that are already out there will keep working. i was hoping that it is just a play store issue and since we deploy with samsung knox it will not be an issue...

I'm part of the Cronosurf team. Our flagship, Cronosurf Wave, is a fully featured chronograph with over 2 million installs. We're getting now bad reviews and emails saying it stopped working on their new Watch7/Ultra watches. Naturally, our faces do use code and can't be reproduced with WFF. Why would Google develop AndroidX/Canvas for creating amazing faces just to kill it a few years down the road? Battery life is important, but so is usability! We think that Google could keep backwards compatibility and let users decide when to run a more functional face vs a super-battery-saving XML-type.
